# Bootstrap grid border issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've following grid system showing flight information (10 columns) and select button & price (2 columns). I am trying to make a border which would separate select button section from rest of flight information, but when I apply border CSS rule, it draws line only half of the way. I suspect that might be a problem of my row/column structure. How do I resolve current issue?

Thanks for any help!

Outcome:

[image]

CSS:

```
.selectButtonColumn{
    border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="container well well-md searchResult">

        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="departFlyRow">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                                <div><b>06:20</b></div>
                                <div>LHR</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <i class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane gly-rotate-90"></i> </i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div>5h 30</div>
                                <div>direct</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <i class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane gly-rotate-90"></i> </i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div><b>12:50</b></div>
                                <div>SVO</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix returnFlyRow">
                            <hr>

                            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
                                <div><b>06:20</b></div>
                                <div>SVO</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <i class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane gly-rotate-90"></i> </i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div>5h 30</div>
                                <div>direct</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <i class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane gly-rotate-90"></i> </i>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div><b>12:50</b></div>
                                <div>LHR</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 selectButtonColumn">

                        <div><b>&pound;100</b></div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Select</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you make us a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or link us a live working site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably put every 12 columns worth of content in separate row, BUT, I don't think you need to do that to achieve what you are after. Try putting a right border on your "returnFlyRow" class.

```
.returnFlyRow{
    border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephanie, works! Could you please explain why did setting border to .returnFlyRow works fine but setting border to .selectButtonColumn draw line only half way?

Comment: I am glad that fixed it for you! You basically have 2 major columns. The large one on the left contains 2 rows nested inside of it. The column on the right doesn't contain these nested rows. Even though it appears that they are equal heights, they really aren't, so the border on the shorter side only goes as far as the content.